# Hidden overflow for PHP data table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a repeating data table like so (I know the php parts are far from correct in this case, but that's not the problem):

```
<table style="overflow:scroll" id="displayTable">
   <tr>
      <td>
      <table id="DataTable">
          <? php repeat>
            <tr>
             <td><? php echo $rowData['Column Name'];></td>
            </tr>
          <? php end repeat>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am after a way to make the overflow scrollable on the table. I have tried
 `<div style="overflow:scroll"></div>`
 like shown above, but that doesn't work. I want it so that the overall height of the 'DataTable' table will be scrollable in the table cell  of 'displayTable' that it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your table with an `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` element with fixed height.

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A Cell</td>
                <td>A Cell</td>
                <td>A Cell</td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>A Cell</td>
                <td>A Cell</td>
                <td>A Cell</td>
            </tr>         
        </tbody>
    </table>       
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.wrapper{
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[Da live fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/nG6pv/1/).